# pointer arithmetic (Triple pointer assignment) in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, nullpointerexception

My scenario is as follows (VC++ code):

```
IDirect3DSurface9 ***ppp;
IDirect3DSurface9* p;
```

I call `CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(  ,  ,  ,&p,null)` and now p will hold the address of D3D surface. So I want to assign `p` to `ppp`.

So I am doing

```
(*(*ppp)) = p;
```

But it's throwing the runtime exception. I don't understand why. Can anyone kindly help me in this?

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing the benefit, but why would you even need a `***ppp`?

Comment: since the variable ppp is uninitialized, the dereferences *ppp and **ppp both are wrong. May I ask why  do you need a IDirect3DSurface9 *** variable in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assignment throws an exception because you are writing to an address pointed to by an uninitialized pointer. You need to allocate memory for the pointer to a pointer array and then to the pointer array before you can make an assignment.

```
ppp = new IDirect3DSurface9**[10];  // Pick the right size here
ppp[0] = new IDirect3DSurface9*[5]; // Pick the right size here, too
ppp[0][0] = p;
```

After you are done with these arrays, don't forget to `delete[]` them.

If using pointers to pointers to pointers is not an explicit requirement, consider using `std::vector<std::vector<IDirect3DSurface9*> >` instead.